# drawerLockMode : 'locked-closed' not working directly with createStackNavigator

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

When I specify `drawerLockMode` direactly with `createStackNavigator` it is not working.

```
const drawerStack = createStackNavigator({
  HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen },
}, {
  headerMode: 'screen',
  navigationOptions: {
    drawerLockMode:'locked-closed'
  }
})
```

But when I use `drawerStack` variable to define `navigationOptions`, it is working.

```
drawerStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    drawerLockMode = 'locked-closed';
    return {
       drawerLockMode,
    };
};
```

Am I doing any mistake when I am directly using it inside `createStackNavigator`?

**Update**

As @bennygenel suggested, we need to user drawerLockMode in drawerNavigator instead of stackNavigator. Here is what i have done.

```
const drawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    drawerStack: drawerStack
}, {
    contentComponent: DrawerComponent,
    navigationOpions:{
       drawerLockMode:'locked-closed'
    }
})
```

But it is not working in this way also. The only way it is working is by using the `const` variable created using `createStackNavigator` or `createDrawerNavigator`

Comment: `drawerLockMode` is property of DrawerNavigator. StackNavigator does not have `drawerLockMode` property in its navigationOptions.

Comment: In that case it should not work by using variable also right? Because it is working when i use it like `drawerStack.navigationOptions = `

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code, it's working for me:

```
   const UserHome_StackNavigator = StackNavigator({
      userHm: {
        screen: UserHome,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          title: 'User screen title',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: 'white',
          },
          headerTintColor: 'black'
        }),
     },
    });

    UserHome_StackNavigator.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
      let drawerLockMode = 'locked-closed';
      //logic here to change conditionaly, if needed
      return {
        drawerLockMode,
     };
   };
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

in case someone need this:

```
const drawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    drawerStack: drawerStack
}, {
    contentComponent: DrawerComponent,
    navigationOpions: ({navigation}) => {

      let routeName = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.routes.length-1].routeName;

      if(['Animation', 'Splash', 'Intro', 'Login', 'Signup'].indexOf(routeName)>=0){
        return {
          drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed'
        }
      }

      return {}
    }
})
```